# Azure Web Jobs - Triggered from queue - triggered or continuous?

Tags: configuration, azure-webjobs, azure-queues

I have a web job I've created and I want to deploy to azure. However I'm confused about the configuration when you create it.

It's a web job that's triggered from an azure storage queue. It works fine locally.

However when I go to create the web job in azure, I'm confused by the choices...my choices are Triggered or Continuous.

If I choose Continuous, I get a choice single or Multi.

If I choose Triggered, I'm given a choice of Scheduled or Manual. I don't want a Scheduled, and I'm not sure what Manual means...that doesn't seem like it's right either.

I know the web job that's triggered from the azure queue is really "polling" and not triggered...so it seems like continuous is the right choice. But I'm not sure.

So the question is...when creating a Web Job that's triggered from an Azure Queue, what is the right deploy configuration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I sounds like you are using the Azure WebJobs **SDK**. In SDK scenarios, even though your individual functions are 'triggered', the WebJob as a while runs continuously (i.e. your exe keeps running and does its own internal triggering). So what you want is Continuous Multi. No reason to use singleton in most cases, and it's not relevant anyway until you scale out to multiple instances.

Comment: Thanks David, I experimented and found that is the case, I wanted continuous.

Comment: The wording is a bit confusion...hopefully someone on the azure team can make that distinction more clear - the difference between Triggered by queue and Triggered by schedule or manually.

Comment: Yes I agree this could be better explained